# How to fix nativebase toast error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.toastInstance._root')

Tags: react-native, react-redux, native-base

I am using nativebase (`"native-base": "^2.12.1"`) at react-native project.
I gonna use show toast on the method in react component class

```
assignTicket(id) {
    return Toast.show({
        text: "Wrong password!",
        buttonText: "Okay",
        duration: 3000,
        type: "success"
    });   
}
```

But I am getting an error at calling this method:

> undefinded is not an object (evaluating 'this.toastInstance._root')

I think this is not nativebase version issue, I am using the latest version.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

For Toast to work, you need to wrap your topmost component inside `<Root>` from native-base.

Answer (score 4):

```
import Root from "native-base";
```

import Root from native base and wrap the whole container/view inside render's return function

```
render() {
    return (<Root>your app-return function code</Root>);}
```

Answer (score 3):

Import Root component from native-base and wrap the entire app in it. This worked for me after days of looking for solution. Wonder why it wasn't stated in the docs

Answer (score 1):

import ROOT and `import ROOT from 'native-base'`  the wrap the to `<Root>{YOUR FUNCTION}</Root>`